# Access, allow mutli non - predefined value

Tags: ms-access, database-design

**Issue :** I created a table on Access and I am trying to add a field in which the user can enter multiple values, but which are not predefined in a list.
Those values must all respect a certain format though.

**My current solution :**

[image]
[image]

I created a combo box with a validation rule.
I specified also Row Source Type as Value List and didn't put any value in the list so that the user can enter them by himself and will only be able to use them if they follow the validation rule.

As you can see in the picture above, the user could add any values to the list, but the value 88 could not be used since it doesn't obey the validation rule.

Unfortunately, this is not a nice solution since all values added by the user will sum up and the list will get bigger and bigger with time...do you know a better way ?

Answer (score 1):

A relational database system deals with related data. It uses *tables* to express these relations.

In your example there is a table where each record is related to a list of values. So have another table to hold this data and express this relation. This new table contains two things:

- the main table's primary key (often this is a single ID, but it can also be a composite key, e.g. a company number plus an employee ID in order to identify an employee)
- the four digit value

Then add a contraint to the value column to ensure it's four digits always.

If it is only *certain* four digits you want to allow for, then you'd even add another table holding these, so you can use them as a reference (i.e. foreign key).

Comment: You are right, you wouldn't create a table of billions of all allowed values. But you would still have a table for the *used* values as mentioned. In your bank example: You wouldn't store a string containing comma-separated account numbers in the clients records (your "current solution"), but have one table for the clients and one for the clients' accounts. The latter would contain the client number and an account number.

Comment: In case of bank accounts there would usually be only one client per account, so the account number would be that table's primary key. In another setting when people can share one account, then both the client number and the account number together would constitute the table's PK.

Comment: Thank you Thorsten, I will try to do it your way. You're right, my bank example was not that good since you have only one account per customer though.